# angular directive - change data inside the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a demo dashboard and inside that dashboard there's the header.
I'm "generating" the header using my "header" directive. (Hope I do it the right way so far)

**app.js**

```
myapp.directive('header', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '../../partials/header.html'
    };
});
```

**header.html:**

```
<h1>Logo</h1>
<span>{{breadcrumbs}}</span>
```

**partials/dashboard.html**

```
<header breadcrumbs="home"></header>
```

can I use the "breadcrumbs" data and deliver it to the header template that I load?

Tried the following without success:

```
myapp.directive('header', function() {
    return {
        breadcrumbs: 'for the sake of this example it can be static',
        templateUrl: '../../partials/header.html'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Exist two ways to achieve the goal:

*you can use isolated scope:*

```
myapp.directive('header', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      breadcrumbs: "@"
    },
    templateUrl: '../../partials/header.html'
  };
});
```

*or `attr` attribute of `link` function:*

```
myapp.directive('header', function() {
  return {        
    templateUrl: '../../partials/header.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.breadcrumbs = attrs.breadcrumbs
    }
  };
});
```

**UPD:**

If you use interpolation in `breadcrumbs` attribute (`<header breadcrumbs="{{breadcrumbs}}"></header>`), above code can to look like this:

*isolated scope:*

```
myapp.directive('header', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      breadcrumbs: "=" //two way binding
    },
    templateUrl: '../../partials/header.html'
  };
});
```

*`attr` attribute of `link` function:*

```
myapp.directive('header', function() {
  return {        
    templateUrl: '../../partials/header.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.breadcrumbs = scope.$eval(attrs.breadcrumbs) //eval interpolation value in this scope
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it this way.

```
myapp.directive('header', function() {
  return {
    scope:{
      breadcrumbs: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '../../partials/header.html'
  };
});
```

you can directly use `breadcrumbs` inside your template.
No need to do anything inside the link function.